Redirect after sign up with woocommerce form with role choice
I use the woocommerce registration form. The user registers and must choose the role. I have 2 user roles and I need to make a redirect for the individual roles.
Example:
user ONE chooses the role "customer", redirect to the url https://mysite.com/shop
user TWO chooses the role "endorser", redirect to the url https://mysite.com/landingpage.
I have tried several plugins but none of them work.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

user_register hook fires immediately after a new user is registered. so you have to add action on this hook. You can add below example code in your active theme's function file.
Example :
add_action( 'user_register', 'redirect_user_based_on_role', 10, 1 );

function redirect_user_based_on_role( $user_id ) {

    // Get the user object.
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // Get all the user roles as an array.
    $user_roles = $user->roles;

    // Check if the role you are interested in, is present in the array.
    if ( in_array( 'customer', $user_roles, true ) ) {

          // Do something.
          wp_redirect( 'https://mysite.com/shop' );
          exit;

    }
    
    if ( in_array( 'endorser', $user_roles, true ) ) {

          // Do something.
          wp_redirect( 'https://mysite.com/landingpage' );
          exit;

    }

}


Ashok,
i put this code in snippet plugin (by the way I'm not a good php man) and boom !! it work GREAT. 10 days of searching and finally I find this page where you solved it for me
THANKS very much !! and Thanks to StackExchange

Great. You can vote my answer so other people can also get benefitted from it. @Max

Ok, i flag the icon green on your response. Hope i made well for vote. Thanks again

This might be a case where careful use of hooks comes in. That's assuming you want to do this in a plugin of your own or the functions.php file of your theme. If you just want an existing plugin or feature in whatever you are currently using, that'd be a bit out of scope here - the registration plugin author might be able to help perhaps.
As this is WordPress Development SE, here is the developer answer.
I don't know what exactly is going on for your set-up as it is unclear what you are running to do the register and chose role system you have.
However, it is very likely that there will be a hook that fires. That hook could be used with a register_action to push some sort of redirect logic.
For example, user_register fires immediately a user is added to the database. Another possibility is register_new_user.
add_user_role fires when a new role is added. This is where I would start looking if it were me.
All of these can be jumped on via the add_action() function using something along the lines of:
 add_action('add_user_role','my_new_function',10,1);

where my_new_function is a function you made. The exact details will depend where you are putting the code.
I would probably add a call to wp_redirect() which is the WordPress way to redirect users.
